# Ways of avoiding full table scans with rare WHERE clauses?

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, optimization, indexing

I'll use this code as an example:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE users AS

SELECT 
    s AS id, 
    (RANDOM() * 200)::int4 AS height, 
    (RANDOM() * 90)::int4 AS age 
FROM 
    generate_series(1, 1000000) AS s;

CREATE INDEX users_height_idx ON users USING btree (height);
CREATE INDEX users_age_idx ON users USING btree (age);
```

Now if I do a query like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE height > 150 
ORDER BY age 
LIMIT 5;
```

The query runs in less than one millisecond. However, if I do something like this:

```
UPDATE users 
SET height = 145 
WHERE age < 30; -- make youngest people all under height 150
```

Now this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE height > 150 
ORDER BY age 
LIMIT 5;
```

takes 3 seconds.

I'm currently encountering this problem in my application where I let the user query for posts and apply various filters to them. In the vast majority of cases, the queries return immediately because there is plenty of matching data (thousands of rows to choose from, we only need 5).

However, if the user is missing some data on their end such that there are very few matches, postgres has to perform a significant scan of the table. I'm dealing with very large datasets and cannot have the query take >5 seconds, for multiple reasons, such as:

1. The user interface will be unresponsive to the user for multiple seconds
2. It's basically a self-DDOS, and severely lowers the performance of my database, because it is spending so much time on this

Are there any workarounds for something like this? I was considering something like setting the max query length to be 1 second, and then returning to the user that their query was too complicated and to suggest filter changes, but that seems like a crappy bandaid solution.

Ideally there would be something where I could maintain the use of an index in a situation such as this, such that the query would return quickly, but I'm not sure what that would look like.

Is the problem just intractable?

Comment: Why is it so slow?  In my hands, your post-UPDATE query is 20 times faster than you report.  Also, it isn't doing a full table scan.  Please post an EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS), preferably after doing `set track_io_timing = on`.

Comment: "(thousands of rows to choose from, we only need 5)"  Unless "age" has a huge number of ties, there are not thousands of rows to choose from.  If you specify "ORDER BY age", it must obey.

Comment: What PG version are you running? I get an index scan on all queries in your example.

Comment: Postgres 12, with cpu_tuple_cost set to 1

Comment: 1? Thats 1000 times higher than the default.

Answer (score 1):

You would probably get better performance on a compound key of (height, age) instead of two individually. Either way, you are still querying against a million records, and from that, it still has to sort the results by age, then stop after the top 5 of the final sorted result set.

Clarification. Your index being based on height and age.  Your WHERE clause is based on height > 150.  So the primary portion of the index is immediately throwing out almost 3/4 of the records (IF EVENLY DISTRIBUTED) from your sample 200 range.  From this, it doesn't even have to consider the others.

The second part by having the AGE in the index too, the engine does NOT have to go back to the raw data page that the records were created.  It has all it needs directly in the index (hence this would be a "covering index").

Whenever you can resolve your where, group by, order by without having to go to the raw data pages will improve performance.  That is probably the missing component you are not yet familiar with.

Comment: Oh, yeah, that reduced it to 5 milliseconds. Can you explain how that works under the hood? I'm having trouble visualizing how it uses that to skip 250,000 rows.

Comment: @RyanPeschel, take a look at my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58551537/why-index-is-used-only-when-forced-but-not-by-default/58558899#58558899   It helps  to try and explain how indexes work and how the engine can quickly fly over a ton of records that never need consideration.  When sorted by multi-columns, the secondary sort can help the optimizer as well.  Let me know if you need more clarification too.  Glad my answer worked for your needs.

Comment: I understand how indexes work in general, just not how a combined one would apply in this use-case. But I'll try to study some more now that I know it helps quite a bit here.

Comment: @RyanPeschel, see revised comment for clarification to your index optimization.

Answer (score 0):

If your users can use any possible search condition including nothing at all, you are in trouble.

During the sales procedure it is nice to promise users that they can search for any combination of conditions, but in practice nobody is going to be happy with that.

For best user experience, sit down with them and try to figure out a handful of search combinations that they need most. Try to find criteria that should always be present for a meaningful search. For substring or prefix search, put a lower limit on the length of the string.

With that, you have a chance to come up with a combination of a few indexes that will make the queries fast and still provide reasonable data modification performance.

If you can't get that, and all combinations are allowed, you are best off putting an index on every column. Then several such conditions can be combined by PostgreSQL with a *bitmap and*. This also works for `OR` conditions, but it won't work for `ORDER BY`.
Data modification performance will probably be quite bad.

And if the user enters no condition or only one that is not selective, you will still get a sequential scan, because it is the fastest way to do it.

You can limit the damage by forcing a `LIMIT` clause on the query. No user wants to be spammed with 500000 results.

Comment: To clarify, I'm using pagination, and there is a `LIMIT 10` on the query. The problem is just that when there is the case that when an `ORDER BY` is combined with a `WHERE`, sometimes the database has to scan through a ton of records until it finds a match, somewhat negating the index. I'm looking for a path around that.

Comment: There is no general way to speed up any query. If the query contains an inequality condition and an `ORDER BY` a different column, there can always be cases where both scanning the rows in `ORDER BY` order while filtering rows and first filtering, then sorting will be slow.